# Looking for a good dev environment for OSGi bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, osgi

I'm currently investigating in the field of dev environment for OSGi bundles.

My goal is to find a way to develop, test and debug with ease the bundles I'll be coding. Besides, I have some "cultural" requirements.

- I want to be able to use java continuous integration servers (typically, [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/))
- As a consequence of that first requirement, I want to have a repeatable, one-click build process. My typical tool for that is [maven](http://maven.apache.org).
- And finally, being  long-term Eclipse user, and having the m2eclipse at hand to merge my eclipse env with my maven one, I obviously want to be able to test and debug with that IDE.

So far, here are the infos I know

- I can use (and have already tested) [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), [maven-ipojo-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/ipojo-maven-plug-in.html) which both offer clean packaging facilities
- I have tested [maven pax](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/) (and eclipse pax) and am not really satisfied with both : maven pax generates a very heavy project, where adding dependencies is very error-prone (the maven [pax:import-bundle](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/import-bundle-mojo.html) command line, with all its arguments, is a hell per se)
- I have taken a look at [Karaf](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-karaf.html), which seems to have some nice direct maven provisionning, but I don't know how to integrate it with my Eclipse, besides using the traditionnal JPDA bridge. However, it seems to be more production-oriented than dev-oriented, and as such may require heavy configuration to fit my need (although the reading of its user manual doesn't revedal that).

Have you got any ideas ? Some maven/eclipse plugins ?

**EDIT** : my goal is not to provide eclipse plugins or features, it is in fact to create independant application, that may be ultimately packaged as webapp (in a similar fashion to, as an example, [sling](http://sling.apache.org)). Is Tycho able to do that ? It doesn't seems so, as its [packaging types](http://tycho.sonatype.org/packagingtypes.html) page only lists eclipse specific packages types (but I may be wrong)

Comment: As VonC says, your requirements pretty much match a combo of Eclipse + Maven/Tycho.  A friend of mine didn't have much luck with Karaf - and the lack of documentation didn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not tested it, but when it comes to maven/eclipse plugin managing OSGi bundles, **[Tycho](http://tycho.sonatype.org/)** seems to be the official project.

See [Create a new OSGi bundle in Eclipse](http://tycho.sonatype.org/how-to-create-a-new-osgi-bundle.html)

Of course, Tycho is part of the [Maven development stack](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/next-generation-maven-development-stack/#more-4113):

[image: Ticho Maven]

---

Other options are mentioned in the [blog entry **Me, OSGi and Maven**"](http://codepitbull.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/me-osgi-and-maven/) mentioned by the OP [Riduidel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15619/riduidel) in the comments:

- [BND](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd) and [Bundlor](http://www.springsource.org/bundlor)
- [pax](http://wiki.ops4j.org/) and [pax-construct](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/)
- [Sigil](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-sigil.html)

Comment: Is it possible to create non-eclipse OSGi bundles using Tycho ?

Comment: @Riduidel: more accurately, Tycho is linked to (eclipse) **equinox** right now. But you can deploy your OSGi built with Tycho bundle outside of eclipse (but in an equinox framework environment).

Comment: +1 I think that Maven/Eclipse/Tycho is the way to go

Comment: Besides, I found that blog post, which seems to sumarize quite well the state of OSGi application building : http://codepitbull.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/me-osgi-and-maven/