# File Management System based on JAVA EE

Tags: java, file-upload, jakarta-ee

I run a small file server for my workgroup. People use SCP, programs like Cyberduck/FileZilla or mount via SSH to upload files.

I would like to add a 'web-interface' which can be used for:

- file upload
- view all files
- adding comments to files
- searching files and comments

It should be based on JAVA EE and running on Tomcat, because we do everything else in JAVA. There are many PHP file manager solutions like [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/). I am basically looking for a JAVA alternative with comments and search features.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: *Do you have any ideas?* Go the google way ?

Comment: I would not ask HERE, if i found something on google ... the answer could also be: "Implement it yourself", "There is something in Rails" ... So what's your point? You would never ask a question like this, would you ;) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635113/looking-for-a-good-dev-environment-for-osgi-bundles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the document management system [alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com). It's based on java and can be run inside tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java Script's FileUpload Object for this 
like.....
FileUpload object, FileUpload properties, accessKey, disabled, form, name, type, value, FileUpload methods - blur(), focus(), select(), handleEvent(), click() and event handlers - onblur, onchange and onfocus